# Datetime SQL statement (Working in SQL Developer)

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I'm new to the SQL scene but I've started to gather some data that makes sense to me after learning a little about SQL Developer. Although, I do need help with a query.

My goal:
To use the current criteria I have and select records only when the date-time value is **within 5 minutes of the latest date-time.** Here is my current sql statement

```
`SELECT ABAMS.T_WORKORDER_HIST.LINE_NO AS Line,
  ABAMS.T_WORKORDER_HIST.STATE        AS State,
  ASMBLYTST.V_SEQ_SERIAL_ALL.BUILD_DATE,
  ASMBLYTST.V_SEQ_SERIAL_ALL.SEQ_NO,
  ASMBLYTST.V_SEQ_SERIAL_ALL.SEQ_NO_EXT,
  ASMBLYTST.V_SEQ_SERIAL_ALL.UPD_REASON_CODE,
  ABAMS.V_SERIAL_LINESET.LINESET_DATE            AS "Lineset Time",
  ABAMS.T_WORKORDER_HIST.SERIAL_NO               AS ESN,
  ABAMS.T_WORKORDER_HIST.ITEM_NO                 AS "Shop Order",
  ABAMS.T_WORKORDER_HIST.CUST_NAME               AS Customer,
  ABAMS.T_ITEM_POLICY.PL_LOC_DROP_ZONE_NO        AS PLDZ,
  ABAMS.T_WORKORDER_HIST.CONFIG_NO               AS Configuration,
  ASMBLYTST.V_EDP_ENG_LAST_ABSN.LAST_ASMBLY_ABSN AS "Last Sta",
  ASMBLYTST.V_LAST_ENG_LOCATION.LAST_ASMBLY_LOC,
  ASMBLYTST.V_LAST_ENG_LOCATION.LAST_MES_LOC,
  ASMBLYTST.V_LAST_ENG_LOCATION.LAST_ASMBLY_TIME,
  ASMBLYTST.V_LAST_ENG_LOCATION.LAST_MES_TIME
FROM ABAMS.T_WORKORDER_HIST
LEFT JOIN ABAMS.V_SERIAL_LINESET
ON ABAMS.V_SERIAL_LINESET.SERIAL_NO = ABAMS.T_WORKORDER_HIST.SERIAL_NO
LEFT JOIN ASMBLYTST.V_EDP_ENG_LAST_ABSN
ON ASMBLYTST.V_EDP_ENG_LAST_ABSN.SERIAL_NO = ABAMS.T_WORKORDER_HIST.SERIAL_NO
LEFT JOIN ASMBLYTST.V_SEQ_SERIAL_ALL
ON ASMBLYTST.V_SEQ_SERIAL_ALL.SERIAL_NO = ABAMS.T_WORKORDER_HIST.SERIAL_NO
LEFT JOIN ABAMS.T_ITEM_POLICY
ON ABAMS.T_ITEM_POLICY.ITEM_NO = ABAMS.T_WORKORDER_HIST.ITEM_NO
LEFT JOIN ABAMS.T_CUR_STATUS
ON ABAMS.T_CUR_STATUS.SERIAL_NO = ABAMS.T_WORKORDER_HIST.SERIAL_NO
INNER JOIN ASMBLYTST.V_LAST_ENG_LOCATION
ON ASMBLYTST.V_LAST_ENG_LOCATION.SERIAL_NO = ABAMS.T_WORKORDER_HIST.SERIAL_NO
WHERE ABAMS.T_WORKORDER_HIST.LINE_NO       = 10
AND (ABAMS.T_WORKORDER_HIST.STATE          = 'PROD'
OR ABAMS.T_WORKORDER_HIST.STATE            = 'SCHED')
AND ASMBLYTST.V_SEQ_SERIAL_ALL.BUILD_DATE BETWEEN TRUNC(SysDate) - 10 AND TRUNC(SysDate) + 1
AND (ABAMS.V_SERIAL_LINESET.LINESET_DATE           IS NOT NULL
OR ABAMS.V_SERIAL_LINESET.LINESET_DATE             IS NULL)
AND (ASMBLYTST.V_EDP_ENG_LAST_ABSN.LAST_ASMBLY_ABSN < '1800'
OR ASMBLYTST.V_EDP_ENG_LAST_ABSN.LAST_ASMBLY_ABSN  IS NULL)
ORDER BY ASMBLYTST.V_EDP_ENG_LAST_ABSN.LAST_ASMBLY_ABSN DESC Nulls Last,
  ABAMS.V_SERIAL_LINESET.LINESET_DATE Nulls Last,
  ASMBLYTST.V_SEQ_SERIAL_ALL.BUILD_DATE,
  ASMBLYTST.V_SEQ_SERIAL_ALL.SEQ_NO,
  ASMBLYTST.V_SEQ_SERIAL_ALL.SEQ_NO_EXT`
```

Here are some of the records I get from the table

```
ASMBLYTST.V_LAST_ENG_LOCATION.LAST_ASMBLY_TIME

2018-06-14 01:28:25
2018-06-14 01:29:26
2018-06-14 01:27:30
2018-06-13 22:44:03
2018-06-14 01:28:45
2018-06-14 01:27:37
2018-06-14 01:27:41
```

What I essentially want is for

```
2018-06-13 22:44:03
```

to be excluded from the query because it is not within the 5 minute window from the latest record Which in this data set is

```
2018-06-14 01:29:26
```

The one dynamic problem i seem to have is that the values for date-time are constantly updating.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. (Make it easy to help you!)

Comment: Please remove all irrelevant parts of that SQL and focus it down to a to-the-point [mcve], this might even help you figure out what the problem is. Control question, the datetime values you are talking about, these are *actual* `DateTime` types, not varchar or something, *interpreted* as `DateTime`? I ask because quite often when people have problems with `DateTime` values it is because they've stored them as strings and doesn't know how to properly handle this. It doesn't seem like you have this problem but I thought I'd ask just the same.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly. I appreciate your help so far. I'm fairly new to this so bare with me as I might have some very basic questions.

Comment: What Im reading as the datatype for these values, it says "DATE"

Comment: also, I added the entire statement in case I may have started the sql wrong. I do apologize for the bad etiquette. But i will learn fast

Answer (score 0):

Here are two different solutions, each uses a table called "ASET".
ASET contains 20 records 1 minute apart:

```
WITH
    aset (ttime, cnt)
    AS
        (SELECT systimestamp AS ttime, 1 AS cnt
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT ttime + INTERVAL '1' MINUTE AS ttime, cnt + 1 AS cnt
           FROM aset
          WHERE cnt < 20)
select * from aset;
```

Now using ASET for our data, the following query finds the maximum date in ASET, and restricts the results to the six records within 5 minutes of ASET:

```
SELECT *
  FROM aset
 WHERE ttime >=   (SELECT MAX (ttime)
                    FROM aset)
               - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE;
```

An alternative is to use an analytic function:

```
 with  bset
    AS
        (SELECT ttime, cnt, MAX (ttime) OVER () - ttime AS delta
           FROM aset)
SELECT *
  FROM bset
 WHERE delta <= INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
```